# How to get the ValueItem value of ListBox item by its index

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox that has a description and a value stored in it (the description is a customer name and the valueitem is that customer's ID in the database) On my form I have two listboxes the one on the left has a full list of customer names and the user then selects from that list and adds the ones they want to associate a user with to the right hand listbox. When I come to save the record I want to store the list of customerIDs in a table so that I can identify which customers this record relates to.

My code loops through the list using a For .. Next loop:

```
For n = 0 To lbxCustomerList.Items.Count - 1
  U.CustomersLinkedTo += lbxCustomerList.Items(n).Value.ToString() & ","
Next
```

U is a User record class and the field CustomersLinkedTo is an NVarchar(255) field that I will build a comma separated list to of the CustomerIDs that the user has allocated this user to.

The issue is that lbxCustomerList.Items(n).Value is not allowed. I am using VB.NET and Dot Net Framework V4.

I have tried loading the ListBox into a ListBox.ObjectCollection variable and then seeing if that allows me to access the ValuItems but that doesn't allow it either.  How do I get the values as opposed to the description text??

EDIT ****
In order to aid those good people who are trying to help me I am adding below the code I use to populate the Customer list and then the code I use to populate the lbxCustomersLinkedTo that contains the customers they have selected:

Populate the list on the left that the user picks Customer names from and adds them to the list on the right that contains the subset the user wants to allocate to to a user.

```
    Private Sub PopulateCustomerList()
    Dim c As New Customer()
    Dim cc As New ArrayList()

    Try
        'Clear list
        lbxCustomerList.Items.Clear()
        lbxCustomerList.DataSource = Nothing

        'Populate from DB.
        cc = c.GetCustomersForDropLists(customerTypeEnum.Active)
        lbxCustomerList.DataSource = cc
        lbxCustomerList.DisplayMember = "DisplayedText"
        lbxCustomerList.ValueMember = "ReturnedID"
        lbxCustomerList.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception
        PEH("PopulateCustomerList", "frmUserSetup", ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Code that adds the items the user selects from the Customers list to the one I am interested in that I use to derive teh Customer ID list I want to add to my user's record.

```
   Private Sub AddToList()
    Dim SelItems As New ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection(lbxCustomerList)
    SelItems = lbxCustomerList.SelectedItems

    Try

        If lbxCustomerList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For n = 0 To SelItems.Count - 1
                lbxCustomersLinkedTo.Items.Add(SelItems(n))
            Next
            lbxCustomerList.ClearSelected()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        PEH("AddToList", "frmUserSetup", ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is an image of the part of the user form I am talking about:
[image: Select Customers Part Of Screen]

@ThePeter - Thanks your routine with a slight modification did the trick.

This is my code in the save routine now:

```
           'Get the Customers an officer works for into a comma separated list.
        'First remove any existing items.
        U.CustomersLinkedTo = ""

        If (lbxCustomersLinkedTo.Items.Count > 0) Then
            For n = 0 To lbxCustomersLinkedTo.Items.Count - 1
                If n = lbxCustomersLinkedTo.Items.Count - 1 Then
                    U.CustomersLinkedTo += WhatValueIsSelectedInListBoxForIndex(lbxCustomersLinkedTo, n) 'Don't add comma to last item.
                Else
                    U.CustomersLinkedTo += WhatValueIsSelectedInListBoxForIndex(lbxCustomersLinkedTo, n) & ","
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

This is your routine modified slightly as it gave an error initially:

```
   ''' <summary>
''' Use this function to get the values of an item in the list box. It works with list boxes that are bound to a DataSet, and those that have been populated via code, or manually populated via the GUI.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="lstBox">The list box you want to find the selected value in.</param>
''' <param name="iIndex">The number of the item in the ListBox that you want the value for.</param>
''' <param name="DesiredReturnValue">By default it returns the hidden return value, but you can ask for the display value if desired.</param>
''' <returns>This function returns a String value.</returns>
Public Function WhatValueIsSelectedInListBoxForIndex(ByVal lstBox As ListBox, ByVal iIndex As Integer, Optional ByVal DesiredReturnValue As SelectByMode = SelectByMode.ByReturnValue) As String
    Dim sReturn As String = ""

    Try
        If DesiredReturnValue = SelectByMode.ByReturnValue Then
            'Returns the value that is not visible, but stored in the "ValueMember" field of the bound ComboBox
            If lstBox.ValueMember.Length > 0 And lstBox.DisplayMember.Length > 0 Then
                'This is a bound listbox.
                Dim drSelectedItem As DataRowView = lstBox.Items(iIndex)
                sReturn = drSelectedItem.Item(0).ToString
            Else
                Try
                    'This listbox was populated in code with display values and return values.
                    sReturn = lstBox.Items(iIndex).ReturnedID
                Catch ex As Exception
                    PEH("WhatValueIsSelectedInListBoxForIndex - Populated Code section", "frmUserSetup", ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        ElseIf DesiredReturnValue = SelectByMode.ByDisplayName Then
            'Return the selected TEXT (visible in the control)
            If lstBox.ValueMember.Length > 0 And lstBox.DisplayMember.Length > 0 Then
                'This is a bound listbox.
                Dim drSelectedItem As DataRowView = lstBox.Items(iIndex)
                sReturn = drSelectedItem.Item(1).ToString
            Else
                sReturn = lstBox.Items(iIndex).ToString
            End If
        Else
            sReturn = ""
        End If
    Catch Ex As Exception

        PEH("WhatValueIsSelectedInListBoxForIndex", "frmUserSetup", Ex.Message)
        sReturn = ""
    End Try

    If sReturn Is Nothing Then sReturn = ""
    Return sReturn

End Function
```

The bit I had to modify to suit my listbox was the line:

```
                       'This listbox was populated in code with display values and return values.
                    sReturn = lstBox.Items(iIndex).ReturnedID
```

With your help, this now works and populates the database field directly.

Siv

Comment: `lbxCustomerList.Items(n).Value is not allowed`  What is Value?  You would have to cast the `lbxCustomerList.Items(n)` to the class object in the list.

Comment: can you add a picture of form? im not getting why you want to loop through listbox instead of just get selected item

Comment: @EssKay The following is a link to a folder on my OneDrive containing the image file: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiEK51i_DpUpj-YEVg2QqLLbxL06Jg

Comment: A separate offtopic question, why don't you remove the entries from the left side when you add to the right? It seems people can enter same client more than once.

Comment: @EssKayyou are right, I had thought about doing that but the issue of getting what was being selected came first and I hadn't got to that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will allow you to find the value of what is selected in a ListBox. You can use it to get either the "hidden" value of a selected item or the displayed value of an item in the ListBox.

*Update: I adjusted the function so it works based on the index value, as per the original question*

```
Public Enum SelectByMode As Integer
   ByDisplayName = 1
   ByReturnValue = 2
End Enum

''' <summary>
''' Use this function to get the values of an item in the list box. It works with list boxes that are bound to a DataSet, and those that have been populated via code, or manually populated via the GUI.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="lstBox">The list box you want to find the selected value in.</param>
''' <param name="iIndex">The number of the item in the ListBox that you want the value for.</param>
''' <param name="DesiredReturnValue">By default it returns the hidden return value, but you can ask for the display value if desired.</param>
''' <returns>This function returns a String value.</returns>
Public Function WhatValueIsSelectedInListBoxForIndex(ByVal lstBox As ListBox, ByVal iIndex As Integer, Optional ByVal DesiredReturnValue As SelectByMode = SelectByMode.ByReturnValue) As String
    Dim sReturn As String = ""

    Try
        If DesiredReturnValue = SelectByMode.ByReturnValue Then
            'Returns the value that is not visible, but stored in the "ValueMember" field of the bound ComboBox
            If lstBox.ValueMember.Length > 0 And lstBox.DisplayMember.Length > 0 Then
                'This is a bound listbox.
                Dim drSelectedItem As DataRowView = lstBox.Items(iIndex)
                sReturn = drSelectedItem.Item(0).ToString
            Else
                Try
                    'This listbox was populated in code with display values and return values.
                    sReturn = lstBox.Items(iIndex).ReturnValue
                Catch Exp As Exception
                    '
                End Try
            End If
        ElseIf DesiredReturnValue = SelectByMode.ByDisplayName Then
            'Return the selected TEXT (visible in the control)
            If lstBox.ValueMember.Length > 0 And lstBox.DisplayMember.Length > 0 Then
                'This is a bound listbox.
                Dim drSelectedItem As DataRowView = lstBox.Items(iIndex)
                sReturn = drSelectedItem.Item(1).ToString
            Else
                sReturn = lstBox.Items(iIndex).ToString
            End If
        Else
            sReturn = ""
        End If
    Catch Exp As Exception
        'You do whatever you want to do here when an error occurs.
    End Try

    If sReturn Is Nothing Then sReturn = ""
    Return sReturn
End Function
```

Comment: An empty Try-Catch?  That's bad programming.

Comment: The try/catch is empty because i expect the user to decide how they want to handle it. Sometimes you throw an error. Other times you log it. It's really up to you. :)

Comment: Probably not. I left it just in case something crazy happened and the variable became null. But sure, you can delete that line of code if it bothers you. I guess i was just being paranoid. :)

Comment: @LarsTech the PEH function (Prog Error Handler) is my custom routine that handles all errors, so it is handled. It just reduces the amount of code in every Try Catch block rather than keep repeating the same thing over and over.

Comment: @ThePeter - Thanks for your help, with slight modification your routine did the job I have marked your answer as the solution as it is now working in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.Value` part or Use this code instead

```
For n = 0 To lbxCustomerList.Items.Count - 1
  U.CustomersLinkedTo += lbxCustomerList.Items(n).ToString() & ","
Next
```

Even easier you can use what @LarsTech Said
This will not require the loop

```
U.CustomersLinkedTo = String.Join(", ", lbxCustomerList.Items)
```

Comment: Use `U.CustomersLinkedTo = String.Join(", ", lbxCustomerList.Items)` to avoid using the loop and having that extra comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that

Comment: Will I not get the text from the listbox as well if I do that? I only want the values from the ValueItem field?

Comment: @Siv We don't know what a ValueItem field is.  In your code, you have it as Value.  You need to document what's in your ListBox — we don't know.

Comment: I just tried the above code and then looked at the field and it contains this: System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection ??

Comment: @Siv We can't help you unless you start answering some of our questions.

Comment: @LarsTech I meant "ValueMember", I have updated my question to show the code that populates the customer list and the code that copies the items from that list into the one I am interested in. This may help you to help me fix this.